# I have a table containing 3 records x,y,z. I want write a query such that x should join with y, y should join with x and z should join with z

Tags: sql

Input:

| Col |
| --- |
| X |
| Y |
| Z |

Output:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| X | Y |
| Y | X |
| Z | Z |

**Approach 1 **

```
SELECT t1.col, t2.col
FROM data t1
CROSS JOIN data t2
WHERE 
  (t1.col = 'x' AND t2.col = 'y')
  OR (t1.col = 'y' AND t2.col = 'x')
  OR (t1.col = 'z' AND t2.col = 'z');
```

**Approach 2 **

```
select t1.col, t2.col 
from data t1 
inner join data t2 on t1.col<> t2.col where t1.col in ('x','y')
and t2.col in ('x','y')
union 
select t1.col, t2.col 
from data t1 
left join data t2 on t1.col= t2.col where t1.col in ('z');
```

Although approach 2 is something I will not be using. Is there any better way to get this done?

Comment: What happened to approach 1

Comment: Approach 1 is fine but my question is if there is any better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Self join could be used:

```
select t1.col as 'A', t2.col as 'B'
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on ( t1.col = 'X' and t2.col = 'Y' )
                      or ( t1.col = 'Y' and t2.col = 'X' )
                      or ( t1.col = 'Z' and t2.col = 'Z' )
```

Comment: Its similar to the cross join approach only. But thanks for answering.